# R, remove row if there is a certain character

Tags: r, dataframe, row

if my data frame looks like this, I want to remove the rows if there is "A" in the A column

```
df    
   A            B       C
1 "4:10:05A"  James    Math
2 "3:10:45"   Tony    Science
3 "3:10:55"   Hong     Math
4 "1:34:23A"  Kim      Math
5 "2:34:13A:  Min     English
```

the result would look like this

```
df    
   A            B       C

2 "3:10:45"   Tony    Science
3 "3:10:55"   Hong     Math
```

Comment: `df[!grepl("A", df$A), ]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg That totally solves OP's problem. You should post an answer.