# Filter rows by presence of string in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, string-matching

This question is similar, but not duplicate of [Delete rows containing specific strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249702/delete-rows-containing-specific-strings-in-r) and [R, remove row if there is a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007025/r-remove-row-if-there-is-a-certain-character?noredirect=1&lq=1). The question is how to remove the row if a string is present anywhere in the row in a dataframe, without having to write the names of the columns in the function. 
EDIT: in the answer remove `!` if the objective is to keep those rows.

Comment: The term generally used is *'filter'* as in *'filter rows where string present/not present...'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way.

Removing all rows which contain "bee"

```
df <- data.frame(c("a", "c", "d", "h"),c("bee","f","g","i"))

df<-df[apply(df,1,function(rowdata){
  !any(grepl("bee", rowdata))
  }),]
```

As @Ferroao pointed out above, in order to keep only rows which contain "bee" remove the `!` (which stands for 'not' in this case).

If you wish to keep rows where every value contained "bee" you could use `all()` instead of `any()`.

Comment: Technically you would not like to do a forloop in a data, to be able to compute the row that has the bee then remove it. that would be tedious to the computer. you can something like `df[!grepl("bee",do.call(paste,df)),]`

Comment: That works, but I dont quite understand how the do.call and the paste are working together, you might consider posting a new answer, and I personally would enjoy an explanation of why it works :)

Comment: haha. you know how `do.call` works right? well then there will be little to explain.. Also this is an old question.. Just going through to see what I missed.